# Prove that for any $a \in \mathbb{R_+}$, show that there is a number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 = a$.

Tags: real-analysis

I was looking at this proof [How to prove that there is a unique positive real number $x$ such that $x^2 = 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602381/how-to-prove-that-there-is-a-unique-positive-real-number-x-such-that-x2-2) today that discussed proving that there is an unique, positive real number $x$ such that $x^2 = 2$. I wanted to generalize the proof to show that for any $a \in \mathbb{R_+}$, there is a number $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 = a$. Any ideas?

Comment: The two answers to the original question work exactly as written if you just replace $2$ by $a$.

Comment: @ckefa (the 2 on the RHS, not the exponent 2)

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, that is the interpretation I had when I wrote my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,
$$f(x) = x^2-a $$

$$f'(x) = 2x$$

$f$ is increasing on $R_+.$

Since, $a$ is positive,

$$f(0) = -a <0$$

Again,
$f(x)$ tends to infinity when $x$ tends to infinity.

Hence, $f$ has exactly one real root on $R_+.$